# Числительные в тексте. Как выделить?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужны ли кавычки при указании размеров, если нужно обозначить их словами, а не цифрами? Например: фотография «десять на пятнадцать».

Answer (score 1):

Нет, кавычки не нужны. В упрощённом виде (разговорном) можно написать, как у Вас, а строго лучше добавить слово *размером*.

Например, *фотография (размером) десять на пятнадцать / три на четыре.*

Answer (score 0):

Если вдруг отключился весь цифровой блок или когда текст не технический и не табличный, возможен вариант выделения числительных скобками: «Фотография (десять на пятнадцать) необходима для оформления». Можно отделить и с помощью тире: «Фотография — десять на пятнадцать», где тире заместит слово «размером». При общей искусственности проблемы подойдёт и двоеточие.